# Angular get request doen't show anything

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make a get request with Angular (my first angular app) and it doesn't work

this is the app.js file

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('getCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
  $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/Users")
  .then(function(response){
    $scope.users = response.data;
  });
}]);
```

and the index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
      <div ng-controller="getCtrl">
          <table>
            <tr ng-repeat = "user in users">
               <td>{{user.name}}</td>
               <td>{{user.lastName}}</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

this is the response of the get request using a rest client

```
 [
        {
            "_id": "5787c061191313250ba4a7ab",
            "created_at": "2016-07-14T16:40:01.076Z",
            "updated_at": "2016-07-14T16:40:01.076Z",
            "lastName": "apellido1",
            "name": "user1",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5787c069191313250ba4a7ac",
            "created_at": "2016-07-14T16:40:09.952Z",
            "updated_at": "2016-07-14T16:40:09.952Z",
            "lastName": "apellido2",
            "name": "user2",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5787c071191313250ba4a7ad",
            "created_at": "2016-07-14T16:40:17.518Z",
            "updated_at": "2016-07-14T16:40:17.518Z",
            "lastName": "apellido3",
            "name": "user3",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5787c95b0b2e8aa6183044dc",
            "created_at": "2016-07-14T17:18:19.643Z",
            "updated_at": "2016-07-14T17:18:19.643Z",
            "lastName": "apellido4",
            "name": "nombre4",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5787ca740b2e8aa6183044de",
            "created_at": "2016-07-14T17:23:00.229Z",
            "updated_at": "2016-07-14T17:23:00.229Z",
            "lastName": "apellido5",
            "name": "nombre5",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5790ec389f3a7a0b0a603be2",
            "created_at": "2016-07-21T15:37:28.671Z",
            "updated_at": "2016-07-21T15:37:28.671Z",
            "lastName": "apellido6",
            "name": "nombre6",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
```

on the web page the result is empty like if the request was empty,I don't know if I missed somthing

Comment: Open console and read the error. Then add missing injections.

Comment: `$scope.users = respose.data;` has a typo should be `$scope.users = response.data;` - response was spelled wrong

Comment: you are not injecting the $http inside ur controller array and function

Comment: Is not injectted this way `app.controller('getCtrl',['$scope',function($scope)`

Comment: @Darren Good Observation :) I think AFS should have tried checking the error from the console first instead of taking so much pain in writing the post. AFS can you let people see the console errors if any.

Comment: Now its solved @KiranJoshi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('getCtrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
  $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/Users")
  .then(function(response){
    $scope.users = response.data;
  });
}]);
```

**Fixed following**

- Inject the correct `$http` dependency into the controller constructor
- Misspell on `response.data`